# Arrangements of $5$ $\alpha$s, $5$ $\beta$s and $5$ $\gamma$s with at least one $\beta$ and at least one $\gamma$ between each two $\alpha$s

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many arrangements of $5$ $\alpha$s, five $\beta$s and five $\gamma$s are there with at least one $\beta$ and at least one $\gamma$ between each successive pair of $\alpha$s?

My attempt:

case 1: exactly $1$ $\beta$ and $1$ $\gamma$ b/w each pair of $\alpha$s $= 96$ ways

case 2: exactly $1$ $\beta$ and $2$ $\gamma$s b/w each pair of $\alpha$s $= 192$ ways

case 3: exactly $2$ $\beta$ and $1$ $\gamma$ b/w each pair of $\alpha$s $= 192$ ways

Don't know how to compute case 4. I mean I know but the answer is not matching.

case 4 would be exactly $2$ $\beta$s and $2$ $\gamma$s b/w each pair of $\alpha$s.

If anyone knows another best possible solution please provide or else just help me with case 4.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should describe your cases in a little different way (results are right). Also there are more cases.

**Case 1.** Between each consecutive pair of $\alpha$ there are one $\beta$ and one $\gamma$

Each pair $\beta,\gamma$ can be placed in two ways: $\beta\gamma$ or $\gamma\beta$

The last $\beta$ and $\gamma$ should be placed 'outside' all alphas - it can be done in $2\cdot 3=6$ ways

Thus there are

$a_1 = 2^4\cdot 6 = 96$

ways

**Case 2.** As above, but there is also **exactly one pair of consecutive alphas** with 2 betas ond one gamma

$\beta,\beta,\gamma$ can be arranged in $\binom{3}{1}=3$ ways: $\beta\beta\gamma$, $\beta\gamma\beta$, $\gamma\beta\beta$

Position of $\beta,\beta,\gamma$ can be selected in $\binom{4}{1}=4$ ways.

The last $\gamma$ can be placed in 2 ways.

Thus we have

$a_2 = 2^3\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 2= 192$

**Case 3.** As above, but there is exactly one pair of alphas with 2 gammas ond one beta (instead of of 2 betas ond one gamma)

Calculations are analogous to these from case 2, so

$a_3 = a_2= 192$

**Case 4:** There is exactly one pair of consecutive alphas with two betas and two gammas between them

$$\beta,\beta,\gamma,\gamma$$ can be arranged in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways and can be placed in $\binom{4}{1}=4$ ways

$a_4=2^3\cdot 4\cdot 6 = 192$

**Case 5:** (not considered in your solution) There is exactly one pair of consecutive alphas with 2 gammas ond one beta and exactly one pair of consecutive alphas with 2 betas ond one gamma

$\beta,\beta,\gamma$ and $\gamma, \gamma, \beta$ can be placed in $4\cdot 3=12$ ways

$a_5 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 12 = 432$

Comment: Everything looks good except your count for $a_5$.  As you observed, $\beta, \beta, \gamma$ can be placed in $4$ ways, which leaves $3$ ways to place $\beta, \gamma, \gamma$.  Each of those can be arranged internally in $3$ ways.  There are $2$ ways to arrange each pair of $\beta, \gamma$, so we should have $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 2^2 = 432$.

Comment: Yes, you are right :). By the way, $438$, not $432$.

Comment: How did you get $438$?  $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 2^2 = 12 \cdot 9 \cdot 4 = 108 \cdot 4 = 432$.

Comment: Sorry, a mistake during computations. $432$ is right.

Answer (score 1):

Using Roman letters and making the $A's$ dividers for simplicity, note that
between two $A's$, you can have $BC$ ($2$ perms), $BBC/BCC$ ($3$ perms) or $BBCC$ ($6$ perms)

The basic **patterns** are:
$00|00|00|00|00|\to 2^5\times 2$ (for outermost $00$ at other end) $=64$

$0|00|00|00|00|0\to 2^5 = 32$

$0|000|00|00|00|\to 3\cdot2^4\times 4\times 2$ (placing $ 000\;$ and for outermost $0$ at other end) $=384$

$|0000|00|00|00|\to 6\cdot2^3\times 4$ (placing $0000$) $=192$

$|000|000|00|00|\to 3^2\cdot2^2\times (4\cdot3)$ (placing the two $000's$) $= 432$

Total $=64+32+384+192+432= \boxed{1104}$